# Connection between 2 STM32F103C8 using I2C

Tags: stm32, i2c, communication

Hello I am new to STM32 and I am trying to learn I2C communication between 2 STM32F103C8 MCUs.  MCU1 acts as the master and MCU2 acts as the slave.  I am using CubeMX to configure the settings however I could not establish a link between the 2 MCUs.  What I wanted to happen is that once I toggle a button connected to MCU1, the LED controlled by MCU2 should be enabled.

Here's my code for the master MCU1:

```
        //Enable Button_LED1 and assign 0xFF data.  0x1F is the slave address
        if(HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(BUTTON_LED1_GPIO_Port, BUTTON_LED1_Pin))
        {
            Buffer_I2C[0] = 0xFF;
            HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, 0x1F, Buffer_I2C, 1, 10);
        }

        //Disable Button_LED1 and assign 0x00 data
        else
        {
            Buffer_I2C[0] = 0x00;
            HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, 0x1F, Buffer_I2C, 1, 10);
        }
```

Here's my code for the Slave MCU2:

```
    {           
        HAL_I2C_Slave_Receive(&hi2c1, Buffer_I2C, 1, 10);
        uint8_t data = Buffer_I2C[0];
        switch(data)
        {
            case 0xFF:
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LED2_GPIO_Port, LED2_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
            break;
            
            case 0x00:
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LED2_GPIO_Port, LED2_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
            break;
            
            default:
            break;
        }
    }
```

May I ask what is wrong with the code?  Thank you for your time.

Comment: Do you have pull-ups attached to the I2C lines? What does your wiring look like?

Comment: Yes both SCL lines joined as well as SDA and I used 4.7k pull-ups for SCL and SDA lines.

Comment: how did you initialize? add more info.

Comment: For the initialization it's just the standard activation of the I2C using 100kHz clock.  I thino the initialization is fine. However for the slave part I have some doubts as the slave address is not included.  How should I include the slave address in the code of MCU2?

Comment: Slave addŕesses (1 or 2 addresses and it is possibpe also to have several addresses) are included in the intialisation (hi2c->Init.OwnAddress1 ...). If you put the related code we may help.